# Using .append() with click() every time on div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the text in a `div` every time I click on it. I tried the following, but its not working:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert('hi');
        $('div').css('cursor','pointer')
        $('div').append('hi')

        $('div').click(function() {
            if ($(this).html('hi') {
                $(this).html('how r u');
            }
            if ($(this).html('how r u')) {
                $(this).html('hi');
            }
        )

        //$(this).html('how r u');
    })
})
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example code has a couple of syntax errors - missing closing brace after your `$("div").click(fn)` and extra closing bracket and brace at the end of the script.

Comment: do you mean toggle? like
`$("div").toggle(function(){$(this).html("Hi")}, function(){$(this).html("How are you?")}); $("div").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if ($(this).html('hi'))
```

try:

```
if($(this).html()==='hi')
```

Full code (you also forgot an "else" with your second "if"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('div').append('hi');

    $('div').click(function() {
        if ($(this).html() === 'hi') {
            $(this).html('how r u');
        } else if ($(this).html() === 'how r u') {
            $(this).html('hi');
        };
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HKWdT/

Answer (score 0):

You still do need to compare the return value of the `.html()` methods:

```
if ($(this).html() === 'hi'){
   $(this).html('how r u');
} else if ($(this).html() === 'how r u'){
   $(this).html('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').css('cursor','pointer')
    $('div').append('hi')
    $('div').click(function(){
        if($(this).html() == 'hi')
        {
            $(this).html('how r u');
        }
        else if($(this).html() == 'how r u')
        {
            $(this).html('hi');
        )
    });
});
</script>
```

This will work too :

```
<div>hi</div>
<div style="display: none">how r you</p>
<script>
$("div").click(function () {
    $("div").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not going to work as condition B will be triggered by condition A. Needs to be `if else`